# Compress small string by converting it's base in PHP?

Tags: php, string, compression

I was wondering if there would be some way to compress a small ASCII string (~100 characters) by combining some of the native PHP compression and base converting functions to produce an even smaller string (`~60 characters).

For example, could I take a string, [gzcompress](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzcompress.php) it, convert it to a number, and then change the base to a system with more values?

The goal is to have a smaller string that is ASCII (perhaps UTF-8) compatible for display.

Comment: What?  Just gzip it and call it good... don't make it bigger again!

Comment: @Brad, I would like to transfer it and/or display it.

Comment: @Xeoncross... Just compress and show the base64 of the output, but this kind of function is completely useless, if you intend to make something smaller.

Comment: I'm not sure what your goal is-- the minimal bandwidth/time you'd save in the transfer of a 60 char vs a 100 char string would likely be less than the extra CPU overhead you'd require to do these manipulations.

Comment: @julio, yes, the computational power required for this out-weighs the bandwidth savings. However, that is not the reason I am seeking to do this.

Comment: There is an entropy limit to the compression of short string. See: `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)` - in a nutshell, there is only so much u can compress before data loss

Answer (score 2):

You could try a dictionary compression like lzw or a golomb code but the compression depends on the data. Without the exact data it's not possible to answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
base64_encode(gzcompress($input));
```

That should do it, but I don't think this will make your original string much smaller.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzcompress.php

Comment: I'm not sure why you posted this - it makes the string longer.

Comment: @Xeoncross, I'm not sure why you posted your question... this is what you wanted.  You can't take a chunk of ASCII, compress it, then represent that compression in an ASCII way without being close to, or bigger than, the original size.

Comment: You don't know how (*and I don't know how*), so that is why I asked this question. Perhaps it isn't possible.

Comment: bin2hex and hex2bin can be used instead of base64 functions